# What is the effect of deleting Software Installation Directory? : Related to its later Complete Uninstallation?

Tags: windows, pdfcreator, citrix-receiver

I have Roxio Burn installed by default by my IT administrator.

Later on I decided to uninstall it because I am rarely burn a CD.

However, it seems that I did not do the correct uninstallation procedure. Moreover, I also regret being frustrated and just deleting the Roxio Program folder on my C Drive.

Right now I have a problem because every time I run simple software like PDF Creator, Citrix Receiver, etc, there will be a Roxio - Windows Installer dialogue box appears (which is distracting).

Does anybody have an idea on how I can solve this problem, please?

Comment: I found a C:\Windows\Installer\{A121EEDE-C68F-461D-91AA-D48BA226AF1C}\RoxioCentral.exe. Is that related to this file?

Comment: It is indeed.  The only reason your having trouble is because you likely do not have the required permissions to uninstall software.  It should have been as simple as using the Add Remove Programs and hitting `uninstall`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Ramhound, However I can't found the name of the sotware in the Add remove programs. But I will try your sugestion

Comment: If you did not run the uninstallation procedure before removing the program directory you have prevented yourself of the ability to uninstall it the correct way.  I suggest you get IT involved.

Comment: Try going into the program folder and find the uninstall file. If your title is correct you have deleted the programs folder for Roxio in which case you won't be able to do an uninstall correctly at this point.... Guess my deleted answer was indeed relevant ;)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping this simple. When you run an uninstall process you are telling your computer the program is gone by taking it through the uninstall process (using the uninstall file within the application). When you simply delete the folder the computer will still think the program exists, but has nothing to point to.

This can create several problems. Anything which might like to this program (in your case a dialog box) will still appear since it thinks the program is there. When you try and uninstall anything associated with the application the add/remove process will be unable to find the uninstall file since you deleted it.

You are always better going through the add/remove process. Even if you have to jump through some hoops like running third party add/remove software to find the uninstall you should do so. Simply deleting the program folder makes things messy.